# Kafka - get lag

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using "node-rdkafka" npm module for our distributed service architecture written in Nodejs. We have a use case for metering where we allow only a certain amount of messages to be consumed and processed every n seconds. For example, a "main" topic has 100 messages pushed by a producer and "worker" consumes from main topic every 30 seconds. There is a lot more to the story of the use case.

The problem I am having is that I need to progamatically get the lag of a given topic(all partitions).

Is there a way for me to do that?

I know that I can use "bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh" to access some of the data I need but is there another way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve that information directly from your node-rdkafka client via several methods:

- Client metrics:

  The client can emit metrics at defined interval that contain the current and committed offsets as well as the end offset so you can easily calculate the lag.

  You first need to enable the metrics events by setting for example `'statistics.interval.ms': 5000` in your client configuration. Then set a listener on the `event.stats` events:

  ```
  consumer.on('event.stats', function(stats) {
      console.log(stats);
  });
  ```

  The full stats are documented on https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Statistics but you probably are mostly interested in the partition stats: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Statistics#partitions
- Query the cluster for offsets:

  You can use `queryWatermarkOffsets()` to retrieve the first and last offsets for a partition.

  ```
  consumer.queryWatermarkOffsets(topicName, partition, timeout, function(err, offsets) {
      var high = offsets.highOffset;
      var low = offsets.lowOffset;
  });
  ```

  Then use the consumer's current position (`position()`) or committed (`committed()`) offsets to calculate the lag.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka exposes "records-lag-max" mbean which is the max records in lag for a partition via jmx, so you can get the lag querying this mbean

Refer to below doc for the exposed jmx mbean in detail . 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#consumer-group-metrics